# Синхронизация действий js

Tags: javascript, синхронизация

Тут я ничего конкретного не спрашиваю. Просто хочу узнать, как сделана мультиплеерная рисовалка, типа 
 `colorillo.com`
Интересует именно принцип синхронизации действий всех пользователей, рисующих на холсте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто как вариант: вебсокеты. Ну или любой полифил для них.

Рисуем - шлём событие на сервер, тот рассылает всем остальным, они его получают, обрабатывают и рисуют такую же штуковину.